# How to deal with subquery which returns more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table:

```
+----+------+------+  
| ID | Col1 | Col2 |  
+----+------+------+  
| 11 |  156 |   48 |  
| 12 |    5 |   22 |  
| 13 |  156 |   32 |  
+----+------+------+
```

What I want to do is

```
SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 = (SELECT MAX(col1) FROM Table1)
```

but since it will be declared and this is written inside a stored procedures that's will give an error that "Subquery returned more than 1 value".
If this error happens I want use 11 AND 12 and `select Min(col2)` of just those id then just give one ID.

Is it possible to catch the two ID's ? If yes how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate answer which will work basically on every DB. (Just use LIMIT instead of TOP on some cases)

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Table1 ORDER BY Col1 DESC, Col2 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time edit: I notice your sql-server tag. However this will work on postgre :(

This will give you the exact answer you are looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Col1) ID 
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE Col1 = (SELECT MAX(col1) FROM Table1) 
  ORDER BY Col2 ASC
```

Comment: after testing on sql server with help of this [site](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) this gives back two rows with the 3 columns and i just want to declare the ID. anyway thanks for ur help^^